# Testing end points of the interval of convergence of a series.

Tags: sequences-and-series

Find the interval of convergence including endpoints of $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}  \frac{n(x+3)^n}{2^n(n^2+1)}.$$ I can find the interval of convergence but I don't know how to test endpoints $x=-5$ and $x=-1$. I don't know whether the series convergences at $x$ = $-5$ and $x$=$-1$ and need help. I don't think the series converges at $x= -5$ and  $x= -1$.

No this is not a duplicate question because the starting index of the series is different.

Comment: Alternating test plus the p-series should do it.

Comment: The starting index has nothing to do with whether it converges.

Comment: The starting index really has little to do with it, and in fact this series the starting index should be $n=1$ as for $n=0$ the first term is zero. The usual way is to substitute for x and apply tests for divergence, the alternating series test will be helpful here

Comment: It is fine if the first term is zero. That does not affect convergence in any way. If a denominator is zero, that is different, but that is not the case here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}  \frac{n(x+3)^n}{2^n(n^2+1)}
$

For $x=-1$,
the series becomes
$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}  \frac{n(2)^n}{2^n(n^2+1)}
=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}  \frac{n}{(n^2+1)}
$.
The terms behave like
$\frac1{n}$,
so the sum diverges.

For $x=-5$,
the series becomes
$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}  \frac{n(-2)^n}{2^n(n^2+1)}
=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}  \frac{(-1)^nn}{(n^2+1)}
$.
The terms behave like
$\frac{(-1)^n}{n}$,
so the sum converges
by the alternating series test
since the terms decrease.

Note:
To show that the terms
decrease in absolute value,
$\frac{n}{n^2+1}$
decreases
is the same as
$\frac{n^2+1}{n}$
increases,
or
$n+\frac1{n}$
increases.

But
$n+1+\frac1{n+1}
-(n+\frac1{n})
=1-(\frac1{n}-\frac1{n+1})
=1-\frac1{n(n+1)}
\gt 0$
for
$n \ge 1$.

Comment: No silly errors, eh?

Comment: Well, would you like to add some?

Comment: I don't need any help - I do it fine all by myself.